# How to filter a dataframe based on the slope of a line between two columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have some data I want to filter, but I can't figure out how.

I created the following plot based on my data via pandas, matplotlib, and seaborn.

[image]

from the following code

```
ax = sns.scatterplot("inverse_docking_score","MW",hue="QPlogPoct",data=df1)

sns.lineplot(data=slope_data, x="X", y="Y")
```

'slope_data' is just the two points you see (10.5, 300) to (12.0, 450)

I would like to make a dataframe from df1 that has all the data below the slope of this line. But I can't figure out how to do that, or what good search terms for my problem is. I've mostly found a lot of very intricate examples that are very hard to follow. I feel like this is probably a super common situation with a very easy solution I can't figure it out.

Comment: Convert your (x0, y0), (x1, y1) line to slope-intercept form (like in algebra class), plug in the x values from your scatterplot, and keep the points where the resulting y values are less than the y values in the scatterplot.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple math. Calculate the parameters of the line (slope and intercept) and check whether the points are above or below:

```
# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'MW': np.random.random(size=100)*250+300,
                   'score': np.random.random(size=100)*3+10
                  })

ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='score', y='MW')
x1, y1 = 10,300
x2, y2 = 12,450
ax.plot((x1, x2), (y1, y2))

slope = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
intercept = y1-slope*x1

df2 = df[df['MW'] < df['score']*slope+intercept]
sns.scatterplot(data=df2, x='score', y='MW', marker='^', ax=ax)
```

[image: points below line]

Comment: not sure if aimed at me, but i upvoted this answer. it's literally exactly what i needed. maybe didn't need 'this is simple math' as an opener (i'm extremely well aware, i've done much more complicated stuff than this - i just got stuck and frustrated), but i'm not gonna protest a solution to my issue that is easy to use for more complex cases.